# messageWhenBadInput not working on lightning input type email

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to display error messgae when email format entered is not correct.

```
<lightning:input type="email" value="{!v.userEmail}" 
                 messageWhenBadInput="Please enter a valid Email Address"/>
```

But if I input something like `abc` in email field, it displays standard error `You have entered an invalid format.` and not the one I added in input tag.

Also, when I enter `abc@gmail` which is also not the correct format, it removes the error message.

Does `messageWhenBadInput` works correctly for `lightning input type:email`

Answer (score 3):

**added**

As you mentioned `email` as type but when you enter ***asdf***, it does not match ***email*** data type as it does not have `@`, it will consider that user entered `Text` data type.

---

You are mentioning type `email` and entering type Text, So it should be **type mismatch** and you should use [messageWhenTypeMismatch](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/specification). Below should work:

```
<lightning:input type="email" required="true"
                     messageWhenTypeMismatch="Not valid Email Address"
                     />
```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't exactly get your point `You are mentioning type email and entering type String`.

Comment: Added in answer

Comment: thanks @salesforce-sas! I did try with `messageWhenTypeMismatch` and it displayed custom message. But it does not check email format correctly. When I input email without domain name i.e without something like `.com`, it doesn't show any error.

Comment: As i mentioned in answer, it checks only for `@` and not domain name. `asd@cvb` is valid email according to lightning. However, you can use `pattern` and `messageWhenPatternMismatch` if you need custom pattern matcher. For understanding, you can ask different question.

Comment: So this begs the question: when is the `messageWhenBadInput` useful?